# xquery failed basic join on medical record number

Tags: xquery, opentext

```
declare variable $mRec := "010155-00";
for $pi in /NTSFP10/dbo_PatRefInfo/ROW
for $pa in /NTSFP10/dbo_Patient/ROW
where $pi/PatientID = $pa/PATID and $pa/PATID = $mRec
return ($pa/PATID)
```

Nothing is returned, but I have verified the mRec exists in each table. both are nvarchar or varchar
[Sample data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI612.png)

Comment: You need to show us your data. Otherwise the only thing we can tell you is that your query is wrong, and we don't know why.

Comment: I mean, the join looks pretty basic, do you see any issue with the join?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your syntax, but for all I can tell without seeing your data, the semantics might be all wrong. For example, about one person a day posts a query (or xpath) on StackOverflow that fails because the elements are in a namespace, and we can only tell if you've fallen into that common trap by seeing the data.

Comment: And I mean actual data, not a screen shot of a small part of it.